# Creating iOS session

Tags: ios, facebook, session, cookies, authentication

I am developing a moblie application for iOS in which you log on facebook and give permissions to the mobile application.

Due to this, you get multiple user data, such as his token, name,...

The problem comes here: We want to log in our server too. For that, we have to create a session (temporary object that exist during the time a user is connected to the mobile application. It is created when the log in is done and it is destroyed when the log out is done) and I do not know how to create it. Those are the technical specifications about creating a session:

1- To create a new user session:

I have got the "Route", the method is "post", public "acess permission" and the parameters are:

```
PARAMS:
provider : string [facebook] uid : string
credentials : [
token: string
secret: string ]
description : text location : string email : string 
info : [
name : string nickname : string image : string email : string
]
```

2- To destroy, the method is "get" and it is restricted to registered users.

Once I have got the information and I have got the facebook log in data, my question is:

What must I do? What I have done till now is:

1- I have written the "route" adress:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mi_url.com/session.json"];
```

2- I have created a nsmutablestring to create a string as the data that the session asks me, with the data previously obtained.

3- I have created a nsmutablestring with the data and the structure that I want, as a template, and after that, I modify it with the values that I have obtained (although those could be done in many ways).

```
 NSMutableString * miJson= [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"{\"uid\": *0, \"credentials\":facebook {\"token\" : *1, \"secret\": *2}, \"provider\": \"facebook\", \"info\": {\"name\" : *3, \"nickname\": *4,\"image\" : *5, \"email\": *6}}"];

[miJson replaceCharactersInRange: [miJson rangeOfString: @"*0"]withString:@"100000389990235"];
            [miJson replaceCharactersInRange: [miJson rangeOfString: @"*1"]withString:_tokens];
            [miJson replaceCharactersInRange: [miJson rangeOfString: @"*2"]withString:_tokens];
            [miJson replaceCharactersInRange: [miJson rangeOfString: @"*5"]withString:@"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/*0\/picture"];
            [miJson replaceCharactersInRange: [miJson rangeOfString: @"*0"]withString:@"100000389990235"];

            [miJson replaceCharactersInRange: [miJson rangeOfString: @"*4"]withString:_name];
            [miJson replaceCharactersInRange: [miJson rangeOfString: @"*3"]withString:_name];
            [miJson replaceCharactersInRange: [miJson rangeOfString: @"*6"]withString:@"beruk@yahoo.es"];

//Here I have created a nsstring with the complete data:
NSString *post2=miJson;
```

4- And here, I have two ways to do the log in to my server, namely, create a session.

4.1- First:

```
            NSData *postData = [post2 dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

4.2- Second (very similar)

```
            NSData* postData= [post2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                                          delegate:self];

            [connection start];
```

I have been watching tons of tutorials, and the previous ways seem the best, but maybe I should do something with afnetworking, as shown below:

```
 NSString *urlsAsString=@"http://mi_url.com/sessions.json";
     NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:urlsAsString];
     NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

     AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

     } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
     {
     //ERROR
     NSLog(@" Error contacting por Facebook: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
     }];

     [operation start];
```

Or, should I do it with asinhttprequest? Maybe with nuserdefault? Or should I give the "post2" data, which is a NSString, to othe data type (Json,...)?

Besides, I guess that I should also develop the cookies to control the data, but I do not know how to introduce them in this code. In fact, Would it work without cookies? I know that specific functions for them must be done (saved, load,...), but, must them be generated at the same time that the session creation or immediately after?

Now, the main thing for me is achieving to create the session, and that the server gives 200 in return. This would mean that is "ok", that the user is correctly logged.

But, how to know it?

In several tutorial it is described that writing "po [response statusCode]" in "all output", after setting a breakpoint in the code, it shows it, but when I try, I only get that there is no response.

How can I check if the server answers about the session creation request? Or, Does it returns me a cookie? And if it does, what must I do with it?

I know that it is a long and complicated question (specially long) and that my English is not so good, but I have been trying everything for weeks and I am desperate.

Thank you very much!!